# Set ActionBarDrawerToggle in center of toolbar or actionbar, android?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar, actionbardrawertoggle

I have created my activity XML through java and also put the navigation drawer.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerLayout = new DrawerLayout(getApplicationContext());
    mDrawerLayout.setLayoutParams(new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    content_frame = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
    content_frame.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    content_layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    content_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    content_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    content_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));;
    tool = new Toolbar(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tool.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tool.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00BBD3"));
    setSupportActionBar(tool);
    tool.setMinimumHeight(getSupportActionBar().getHeight());
    content_layout1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

    content_layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    content_layout1.setLayoutParams(new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(320,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.START));
    t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    t.setText("XYZ");

    ivBottom = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    par.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    ivBottom.setLayoutParams(par);
    ivBottom.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mDrawerList = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
    mDrawerList.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    content_layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    content_layout.addView(tool);
    content_layout.addView(t);
    content_frame.addView(content_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(content_frame);
    content_layout1.addView(mDrawerList);
    content_layout1.addView(ivBottom);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(content_layout1);

    setContentView(mDrawerLayout);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new SideAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            menuTitles, menuIcons));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, tool,
            R.string.action_settings, R.string.action_settings) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

If I put the toolbar height to wrap content this is the toolbar/action bar I get

As you see I do not get the action bar preferred height.
[image]

Now if I keep the height to 100 this is the toolbar/action bar I get
As you see the actionbar toggle icon does not center with the content

[image]

I have 2 options:

1. Either the size of toolbar comes to default size
2. Or make toggle be in center

I have tried lot of things but I still can't figure it out.
Please help me out.

Menu XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.drawermenu.JavaDrawerActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Java code for menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    // menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: can you change par.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;  to par.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the size of toolbar comes to default size

If you means the default Action-Bar height and you use the built-in theme, the attribute "android:actionBarSize" value is exactly the Action-Bar height in current theme. If you want set the height in Code, snippet are as follow.

```
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        int actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

> make toggle be in center

As far as i know, there isn't an official way to change layout parameters of the "toggle drawable", but you can do it using the following code(test on android 5.0 nexus-5, use support-v7 Drawabletoggle and Toolbar):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mToolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
        // make toggle drawable center-vertical, you can make each view alignment whatever you want
        if (tool.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageButton) {
            Toolbar.LayoutParams lp = (Toolbar.LayoutParams) mToolbar.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams();
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        }
    }
```

So, you can see it is just a common way to set layout-gravity of view, what need to know is the toggle drawable is an **ImageButton**. If you want every view in Toobar to center-vertical, just set the corresponding layout-gravity of view. Have fun! :)

Comment: In my current code settings menu is not appearing. Can you also help out with it?

Comment: @Shink do you mean the "Action buttons"? if it is please show the corresponding xml file?

Comment: try to replace `app:showAsAction="never"` with `android:showAsAction="never"`.

Comment: @Shink sorry about that, I tried and it works in nexus5(5.0), do know why...  By the way, `new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, tool,R.string.action_settings, R.string.action_settings)` should be replaced with the other constructor, which is indicated by official doc.

Comment: This is the only solution if you dont want to set toolbar height as ?actionBarSize   THANKS!!

Answer (score 13):

Another more easier way do is set the minimum height on the Toolbar, as by default it uses the size of the action bar

```
 android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

so in your toolbar if you set it to 100dp

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:minHeight="100dp"
```

It will align with in the middle of the toolbar.

Comment: Wow this is a much better way of doing this, much tidier! thanks.

Comment: Thank you buddy. Great answer.

Comment: sweet and short :)